# Document Object Model - Differences between browsers

Tags: dom

What are the primary differences between DOM in different browsers(Mozilla FireFox, IE, Opera, other)? If You can, please, give me some examples.

Comment: That's a very loaded question that is best answered by a long article. I would start googling if I were you.

Comment: I try to write article about DOM and I am looking for differences between DOM implementations. I found this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-browser . However, I think there are more differences between the DOM in different browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start here:

http://www.quirksmode.org/

And as Myles said in his comment, the list is long and complex. Do you have a specific problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can start here:

- [webdevout.net](http://www.webdevout.net/browser-support-dom)
- [compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html)
- [DOM Core](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html)
- [DOM/events](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html)
- [DOM/css](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html)
- [DOM/traversal](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_traversal.html)